# Protocol buffers in Go: cannot find package

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm following the [Protocol Buffer for Go tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial#compiling-your-protocol-buffers) but I have the following problem:

1. I create the addressbook proto definition

> ```
> syntax = "proto3";
> package tutorial;
>
> message Person {
>   string name = 1;
> ...
> }
> ```

2. I successfully run the compiler and generate the go code
3. I try to import the pb package but it fails

Here is exactly what happens: I specifying the `--go_out` to be same as my proto definition: (`protoc --go_out=. addressbook.proto`)

then in same folder, I create a test.go with these simple lines:

```
package main

import "tutorial"
```

but `go build test.go` returns error:

```
test.go:3:8: cannot find package "tutorial" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/tutorial (from $GOROOT)
    /home/vagrant/go2/src/tutorial (from $GOPATH)
```

then I change `test.go` to this:

```
package main

import "protobufs/tutorial"
```

and get this error:

```
test.go:3:8: cannot find package "protobufs/tutorial" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/protobufs/tutorial (from $GOROOT)
    /home/vagrant/go2/src/protobufs/tutorial (from $GOPATH)
```

but if I change the import to only:

```
package main

import "protobufs"
```

it finds that there's a "tutorial" package in that location:

```
test.go:3:8: found packages tutorial (addressbook.pb.go) and main (list_people.go) in /home/vagrant/go2/src/protobufs
```

What am I doing wrong ? How should the import look like in order to make this work ?

Thank you !

FYI: a snippet of my go env:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/vagrant/go2/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/vagrant/go2"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

Comment: In order for the compiled protobuf to be importable as "tutorial", you need to set `--go_out=` to `$GOPATH/src/tutorial`.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks ! ... it seems that I need to read more about import in golang, since I don't understand why I cannot import it from the same directory

Answer (score 2):

This question showed my lack of understanding of Go's packaging. After some reading, here are my conclusions/rules:
1. one package per folder: all the .go files in directory "**abc**" will indicate `package abc`
2. you can't have package `main` and package `abc` in same folder
3. `go install` creates package object `abc.a` in `$GOPATH/pkg/GOOS_GOARCH/<path_to_abc_excluding_abc>`
4. for the package `main` in folder `$GOPATH/src/x/y/z/foo/` then `go install` compiles and installs an executable called `foo` (the name of the last directory in the path) in `$GOPATH/bin`

Now, back to the initial question: the directory `$GOPATH/src/protobufs` contains multiple packages:
- the compiled protobuf with the package name `tutorial`  and
- the `main` package in `test.go`
This contradicts with the above listed rules.

I believe that one elegant solution is:
- assuming I'm in `$GOPATH/src/protobufs`
- create a subdir called `tutorials`
- install the compiled protobuf in that subdir:  `protoc --go_out=./tutorial ./addressbook.proto`
- the `test.go` can now have `package main` and `import "protobufs/tutorial"`

Thanks for putting on the right track !

Answer (score 0):

check [GO workspace](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html#Workspaces):

```
A workspace is a directory hierarchy with two directories at its root:

src contains Go source files, and
bin contains executable commands.
```

The tutorial is based on this structure, i.e.,

```
src/
    github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/examples/
      tutorial/
         addressbook.pb.go
      list_address.go
```

In the [makefile](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/635156e40637d65650e91a21afec10ad8fac5c19/examples/Makefile#L33) of that tutorial, it generates `pb.go` under `examples` dir through:

```
mkdir -p tutorial
protoc $$PROTO_PATH --go_out=tutorial addressbook.proto
```

Under the [add_person.go](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules), it just assumes the import path is under `worksapce/src`, which is `$GOPATH/src` mentioned above:

```golang
import (
....

pb "github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/examples/tutorial"
// find through $GOPATH/src/github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/examples/tutorial
)
```

What you need to do is to set the right `GOPATH` and generate that `pb.go` under `$GOPATH/src`

```
protoc -I=. --go_out=/Users/guihaoliang/Playground/go/my_workspace/src addressbook.proto
```

where `.` refers to where the `addressbook.proto` is located.

The `GOPATH` workspace is going to be superseded by [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) so that you don't have to maintain the `src` and `bin` structure. The protobuf example is not using the new module structure.